# I need to stop multi thread code from running

Tags: python

I'm trying to stop the code from running if the user presses ctrl+shift+c. I use the code below. Unfortunately sys.exit() stops only "wait_for_ctrl_shift_c" function, but not "main_func". What should I use to stop them both?
Thanks.

```
def wait_for_ctrl_shift_c():
    print ('wait_for_ctrl_shift_c is working')
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+shift+c')
    print('wait_for_ctrl_shift_c was pressed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    sys.exit()



def main_func():
    a=0
    while True:
        print ('Working2 ',a)
        a=a+1
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = wait_for_ctrl_shift_c).start()
    Thread(target = main_func).start()
```

Comment: can'y you add the same condition to your main function as well?

Comment: I cannot add keyboard.wait('ctrl+shift+c') to my main function, because it won't go farther if I do not press "ctrl+shift+c". That's why it is called WAIT.

Comment: in that case have each function monitor for the `SIGINT` signal. it's available in the `signal` package in the standard library

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it. First of all you have 3 threads, one main thread and the other 2 (infinite loop & keyboard one) you create.

You can register signals and handle it, also you can call interrupt_main to interrupt main thread (not the while loop thread). Interrupt will go to **main** exception handler. Also instead of True i changed the second thread to have an attribute to check if it should run for clean exit.

```
import os
import threading
import time
import sys
import _thread

def wait_for_ctrl_shift_c():
    print ('wait_for_ctrl_shift_c is working')
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+shift+c')
    print ('exiting thread')
    _thread.interrupt_main()
    sys.exit()

def main_func():
    a=0
    t = threading.currentThread()
    while getattr(t, "run", True):
       print ('Working2 ',a)
       a=a+1
       time.sleep(1)

    print ('exiting main_func')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = wait_for_ctrl_shift_c)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = main_func)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
    except:
        print ('main exiting')
        t2.run = False
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Also check signal handling, a better way to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

Open shell in another window, type `ps` to list running processes, and kill the Python one (via `kill 3145`, if `3145` is its `PID`) to stop them both. This way we kill the process within which these threads run.

Comment: I killed the process called "pythonw.exe". There are 4 of them. I killed all. I work in Spyder. Spyder crashed as well. So your solution definitely works, but I would prefer if Spyder remained open.
def close_python():
    PROCNAME = "pythonw.exe"

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
#        print(proc.name())
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            print('Python was closed')
            proc.kill()